# Can i view cvs repository file without checkout?

Tags: cvs

i wanted to check if particular function is available is CVS repository. For this task i can't just do cvs checkout. Can i view cvs repository file without checkout?

Answer (score 1):

just did cvs co -h

```
      cvs checkout [-ANPRcflnps] [-r rev] [-D date] [-d dir]
        [-j rev1] [-j rev2] [-k kopt] modules...
            -A      Reset any sticky tags/date/kopts.
            -N      Don't shorten module paths if -d specified.
            -P      Prune empty directories.
            -R      Process directories recursively.
            -c      "cat" the module database.
            -f      Force a head revision match if tag/date not found.
            -l      Local directory only, not recursive
            -n      Do not run module program (if any).
            -p      Check out files to standard output (avoids stickiness).
            -s      Like -c, but include module status.
            -r rev  Check out revision or tag. (implies -P) (is sticky)
            -D date Check out revisions as of date. (implies -P) (is sticky)
            -d dir  Check out into dir instead of module name.
            -k kopt Use RCS kopt -k option on checkout. (is sticky)
            -j rev  Merge in changes made between current revision and rev.
    (Specify the --help global option for a list of other help options)
```

-p option came to rescue.

```
cvs co -p BRANCH_TAG gui/xyz.pm
```

achived my purpose. It did checout on standard output stream, end result is i am able to view file content and grep it for anything using pipes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RCS command checkout command co, as shown below.

```
c:\repo> co -p readme.txt,v
```

.. prints final version of readme.txt on the screen ..

The man page is here http://linux.die.net/man/1/co
CVS also uses RCS to maintain its repo.

WinCVS GUI works out of the box. 
Avoid the buggy python ViewVC server, it was unable to parse many ,v files.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if you are using an IDE like Eclipse, all you need to do is configure and add your CVS repository like this: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-92.htm

Once this is done you can go to the respective HEAD\BRANCH and then view the file from there by right clicking on file and opening it. This way you have not checked out the file to your local system but viewed it in the CVS repo.

If you are not using eclipse, you can use command line with CVS Commands.
Command:
cvs diff filename

would give you information and the difference with the last checked in version.

More info: http://www.badgertronics.com/writings/cvs/command-line.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is as good as checking out repo to eclipse workspace. this i can do even cvs command line tools. This will add overhead to checkout and all cvs module files. I am not looking for this.

Comment: Viewing files in CVS repository is not checking the file out. You have actually not checked the file out to your machine. You are still viewing it on the CVS server.  The CVS repository structure is a view to the files on CVS server. There is no overhead of Checkout, as you are not checking out any file.